# Use pages from a Windows Phone App inside another Phone App

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 Solution which consisted of 3 projects (2 class libraries and one WP8 app).
This project has some XAML pages like (MyMainPage, MySearchPage, MyResultPage, etc..) with their ViewModel classes.

Now i have created a new Windows Phone 8 solution from scratch.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to reference the first App so I can re-utilize those pages without having to copy the source code to my new solution?

I've tried referencing the 2 dlls from the class libraries and the .exe from the WP8 project. But i get exceptions when starting the new App.

When doing something like  `MySearchPage page = new MySearchPage()`  i get this exception:

```
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in MyFirstWP8App.EXE but was not handled in user code
```

and sometimes thi one too on startup:

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in PivotTest.EXE but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Comment: are your both projects located within the same solution?

Comment: No.  I have two different solutions.  One for the W8 app and one for the W8.1 app